# No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method OnValidate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

i am new in LINQ and working in asp.net using Linq to Sql in which i am trying to validate the data model field.. i have two project(Class Library) in my application "Common" & "Administration" which means two different namespaces and my application is layer based "Data Access Layer" and "Business Process Layer"

i am using OnValidate method in Generated Class to validate the field

**Namespace Common**

```
[Table(Name="dbo.tblaccounts")]

    public partial class tblaccount : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Extensibility Method Definitions

            partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
            {
                if (!Char.IsUpper(this._ACCOUNT[0]))
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(
                        "Garage Name must start with an uppercase letter.");
                }
            }
    }
```

**Namespace Administration in Data Access Layer**

```
internal bool SaveGarage(tblaccount oGarage)
        {

            ChangeSet changeSet = null;
            int changeCount = 0;
            using (CommonDataContext GarageDC = new CommonDataContext(Settings.ConnectionString))
            {

                GarageDC.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
                try {
                if (oGarage.RowVersion == null)
                {
                    //insert Garage details
                    GarageDC.tblaccounts.InsertOnSubmit(oGarage);

                    changeSet = GarageDC.GetChangeSet();
                    changeCount = changeSet.Inserts.Count;
                    GarageDC.SubmitChanges();
                    Message = "Garage saved successfully.";

                }
                else
                {
                    //updates a Garage
                    GarageDC.tblaccounts.Attach(oGarage, true);
                    changeSet = GarageDC.GetChangeSet();
                    changeCount = changeSet.Updates.Count;

                    try
                    {
                        GarageDC.SubmitChanges();
                        Message = "Garage Updated successfully.";
                    }
                    catch (ChangeConflictException cex)
                    {

                        foreach (ObjectChangeConflict conflictObject in GarageDC.ChangeConflicts)
                        {
                            // expose the neccessary information,
                        }

                    }

                }
                }
               // here i want to get the validation exception
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Message = ex.ToString();

                }

            }
            if (changeCount > 0) { return true;

            }
            else { return false; }
        }
```

please suggest me how to validate a data model field if you are using different namespace in different project in an application... i have already referenced a common namespace dll with Administration project

**when i build my project i am getting this error**

> No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial
>   method
>   'PeaceStar.Common.Data.tblaccount.OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction)'

Comment: why did you define your method OnValidate as "partial"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please suggest me how to validate a data model field if you are using
>   different namespace in different project in an application

I would give you completely different and easy solution using DataAnotations. This approach is much cleaner with less code.

Lets say your model is going to be -

```
public class NewModel
{
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z][A-Za-z]{3,19}$", ErrorMessage="First character of name should be capital")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the model we say that first character of the entered name should always be capital.

Then we have in our Index View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.NewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "NewModel", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

And when Submit button is clicked, we can do our validation in Submit Action by using ModeState.IsValid -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(NewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Index");

        return View();
    }
```

So when we enter work like **rami** -

[image]

An when we enter correct work like **Rami**, validation will be passed and Submit view will be rendered.